# Send Choices in Serilizer Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py:

```py
class Distributor(models.Model):
    class ModeChoices(models.IntegerChoices):
        physical = 1, _('physical')
        digital = 2, _('digital')

    class StatusChoices(models.IntegerChoices):
        publish = 1, _('publish')
        pending = 2, _('pending')
        dont_publish = 3, _('dont_publish')
```

serializers.py:

```py
    modes = serializers.DictField(source=dict(Distributor.ModeChoices.choices))
```

not working ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no explict choices field here use instead

```
class Distributor(models.Model):
 class ModeChoices(models.IntegerChoices):
     choices= (
         (1, _('publish')),
         (2, _('digital')),
         )
```

**serializers.py**

```
 modes = serializers.DictField(source=Distributor.ModeChoices.choices)
```

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'